# the decimal value of each fraction on a new line with 6 places after the decimal

Tags: r

Given an array of integers, calculate the ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero. Print the decimal value of each fraction on a new line with 6 places after the decimal.

When I run my code below, it prints strings instead of decimal numbers.

```r
plusMinus <- function(arr) {
    size <- length(arr)
    pos <- length(arr[arr > 0])
    neg <- length(arr[arr < 0])
    zero <- length(arr[arr == 0])
    x <- pos / size
    y <- neg / size
    z <- zero / size
    print(sprintf(x, fmt = "%#.6f"))
    print(sprintf(y, fmt = "%#.6f"))
    print(sprintf(z, fmt = "%#.6f"))
}
      
arr <- c(1, 1, 0, -1, -1)
arr <- as.integer(arr)
plusMinus(arr)
```

I expect

```
0.500000 0.333333 0.166667
```

but the actual output is

```
[1] "0.500000"   
[1] "0.333333"    
[1] "0.166667"
```

Comment: Use `cat` instead of print

Comment: Or if using print, dont use `sprintf` Just do `print(x,6)`

Answer (score 1):

```
'  public static void plusMinus(List<Integer> arr) {
// Write your code here
Float positive=0f;
Float negative=0f;
Float zero=0f;
Integer sizeOfarray=arr.size();
for (Integer i : arr) {
    if(i>0) positive++;
    else if(i<0)negative++;
    else zero++;
}
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#0.000000");
System.out.println(df.format(positive/sizeOfarray));
    System.out.println(df.format(negative/sizeOfarray));
System.out.println(df.format(zero/sizeOfarray));

}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the modification you need.

```
plusMinus <- function(arr) {
  size = length(arr)
  pos = length(arr[arr>0])
  neg = length(arr[arr<0])
  zero = length(arr[arr==0])
  x = round(pos/size, 6)
  y= round(neg/size, 6)
  z= round(zero/size, 6)
  return(c(x, y, z))
}
```

With: `arr = c(1, 1, 0, -1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1)`

The result is: `[1] 0.333333 0.444444 0.222222`

Comment: What will happen if there are no 0 in the array?. Also simply do `mean(x>0)` for positives for example

Comment: Can you show the result if you had `arr=c(1,1,-1,-1)`?